# How can I give Directory to Inputstream from Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)

Tags: android, csv, android-intent, inputstream

Hi all I am working on my final year project, may any one please guide me that how to provide the file to Inputstream from Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT), I want to take the file from sdcard memory to application:

I want to read CSV/txt file.

below is my code in which i want to implement the filepath should get from Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).
Currently it is working correctly from resource file.

````
    private void readcustomerfile() {

        InputStream st=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.customer);

        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(st, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))  );
        int a=0;
        String line="";
        String line1="";
        while (true) {
            try {
                reader.readLine();

                if ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){

                    String[] text=line.split("," );
                    if(line.toString().trim().equals("")){
                        System.out.println(line+"\n");

                    }
                    System.out.println(

                            text[0]+"#"+
                            text[1]+"#"+
                            text[2]+"#"+
                            text[3]+"#"+
                            text[4]+"#"+
                            text[5]+"#"+
                            text[6]+"#"+
                            text[7]+"#"+
                            text[8]+"#"+
                            text[9]+"#"+
                            text[10]+"#"+
                            text[11]+"#"+
                            text[12]+"#"

                    );
                    System.out.println(a++);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
```
There I am assigning file from app resource folder but I want to assign from user directory by intent.
```
 InputStream st=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.customer);
```
````

Comment: Start showing onActivityResult code.

Comment: I try this //    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("text/*");
       startActivityForResult(intent,READ_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

Comment: @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String path = uri.getPath();
                path = path.substring(path.indexOf(":") + 1);
                Toast.makeText(this, "" + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                readfile(path);

            }
        }

Comment: private void readfile(String path) {
        File file=new File(path);
        StringBuilder text=new StringBuilder();
    try{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line="";
        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){

            text.append(line);
            text.append("\n");
            System.out.println(text);
        }
        br.close();

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error:"+e);
    }


    }

Comment: But it appears Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: User.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: I will not read all your comments. Please remove them. Put your code in the normal way in code blocks in your post. And put what you have to say in your post too.

Comment: Thank you dear there was a little error U solved it.

Comment: But! it is working on AVD Android 7.1.1 API 23

Not working in my physical device I have android 10 in that it shows 
Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/User.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: Thank you sir for your quick response god bless you with a good healthy and wealthy life.